# Distrubution Code signing Mapbox.framework failed for iOS

Tags: react-native, mapbox, react-native-mapbox-gl

I have an issue with uploading my app to the app store when signing the app. I got Code signing "Mapbox.framework" failed.

I have set up the build phase as instructed here https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/blob/master/ios/install.md.
Checked the log for this and all looks ok.

This is the codesign log:

```
Copy .bcsymbolmap files to .xcarchive
Stripping frameworks
Stripped ./Mapbox.framework/Mapbox of architectures: i386
Code Signing ./Mapbox.framework/Mapbox with Identity iPhone Developer: XXX
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign XXX --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements ./Mapbox.framework/Mapbox
```

This is where the issue comes up. Distribution log:

```
2019-08-04 03:14:24 +0000  /var/folders/nv/djgpql5d4cz05dvpkq49w0900000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.QkU/Root/Payload/XXX.app/Frameworks/Mapbox.framework: replacing existing signature
2019-08-04 03:14:25 +0000  /var/folders/nv/djgpql5d4cz05dvpkq49w0900000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.QkU/Root/Payload/XXX.app/Frameworks/Mapbox.framework: code object is not signed at all
2019-08-04 03:14:25 +0000  /usr/bin/codesign exited with 1
```

If anyone else had the same issue, please let me know how did you fix it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been resolved. Solution https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/issues/296#issuecomment-520832063