# Upload error Code signing Mapbox.framework failed

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

It may be duplicate. but none of the existing solutions is working for me. help plz..

I am struggling with this error from last one week. when i try upload the app into testflight am getting this **Code signing "Mapbox.framework" failed** error. when i try to added this map framework in **embedded binaries** and it is automatically linked in linked frameworks as normal way but i could not able to upload it. when i remove from Embedded binaries i could able to upload perfectly.. but map framework required for app functioning..

When i try upload the framework in Embedded binaries i am getting error with below report,

```
XcodeDistPipeline.~~~rQ8d1p/Root/Payload/School Bus Tracking.app/Frameworks/Mapbox.framework: replacing existing signature
2019-12-19 13:35:41 +0000  /var/folders/9t/9pb1bf150wv3gs2bfvyfxqpm0000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~rQ8d1p/Root/Payload/School Bus Tracking.app/Frameworks/Mapbox.framework: 

code object is not signed at all

2019-12-19 13:35:41 +0000  /usr/bin/codesign exited with 1
```

and

```
IDEDistributionContext: 0x7fb77a1c3880; archive = IDEArchive: 0x7fb77a347200, 

distributionMethod=(null), team=(null)
```

Comment: Your issue is very project setting-specific.
You should provide more details regarding your Build Settings, how did you install Mapbox, etc.. Did you try to install it via [Cocoapods](https://www.mapbox.com/install/ios/cocoapods/) or [Carthage](https://www.mapbox.com/install/ios/carthage/).
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30653768/1040347) is similar issue, also on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29076321/how-do-you-fix-code-object-is-not-signed-at-all-in-subcomponent-in-xcode-6-m) and also a [duplicate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57343630/1040347). Extend a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. setting up correct $(ARCHS_STANDARD)** 
   It was armv7, arm64, armv7s and arm64e like this. I have removed valid architecture column from Architecture section.

[image]

**2. Need to set correct framework path (if you use run script)**
we need set correct framework path for both linking and embedded section.

**3. Do cross check framework build** 
Do cross check if framework build working correctly with supportive architecture. after archive the final version should be : ARMV7 and ARMV64